# How to define expression selection nested one-to-one relationship in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to run a Linq-to-Entity that contains this `Expression` into Entity Framework.

Not Working:

```
//2 seperated expressions, 1st expression calling the 2nd expression
public Expression<Func<User, UserDto>> UserToDtoExpr() {
    var expr = AddressToDtoExpr();
    return x => new UserDto() {
        Id = x.Id,
        Name = x.Name,
        Address = expr.Compile()(x.Address)
    };  
}
public Expression<Func<Address, AddressDto>> AddressToDtoExpr() {
    return x => New AddressDto() {
        Id = x.Id,
        City = x.City,
        Country= x.Country
    };
}
```

**Exception**: `The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.`

Now, I if hardcode and nest it into one `Expression` and put it into Linq-to-Entity then it works:

```
//hardcode combined together into 1 expression with nested object
public static Expression<Func<User, UserDto>> UserToDtoExpr() {
    return x => new UserDto() {
        Id = x.Id,
        Name = x.Name,
        Address = New AddressDto() {
            Id = x.Address.Id,
            City= x.Address.City,
            Country = x.Address.Country
        }
    };  
}
```

But I don't want to hardcode it like the 2nd way, because I want to modularise and reuse these `Expression` functions. How do I fix up the 1st way to make it work? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [LinqKit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit/)'s `AsExpandable()` to achieve this.

First, change your expression to use LinqKit's `Invoke()` (extension method) as follows:

```
Address = expr.Invoke(x.Address) // instead of expr.Compile()(x.Address)
```

Then use `AsExpandable()` on your `DbSet<T>`:

```
var results = context.Users.AsExpandable().Select(UserToDtoExpr());
```

Read [this](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) to understand the problem with nested expressions.

Comment: Is it difficult to achieve this structure without using LinqKit?

Comment: `expr.Compile()` returns a `Func<Address, AddressDto>` which EF cannot translate into SQL. *Something* must be done to overcome the problem and `LinqKit` does it elegantly and efficiently. If you don't like the idea of introducing new code and not going to write the workaround yourself, I assume you'll have to construct your Expression with regular Lambdas.