# Linq to Entities: How to create a reusable custom expression that returns a collection/iqueryable

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, dry

I would like to create a reusable method that I can use in Select() projections.  Here is a simple example:

```
public partial class Product
{
    public IQueryable<ProductImage> GetProductImages(bool ActiveOnly)
    {
        return this.ProductImages.Where(i => !ActiveOnly || i.IsActive);
    }
}

public class App
{
    public void Main()
    {
        var product = db.Products.Select(p => new {
            p.Name,
            p.GetProductImages(true)
        }
    }
}
```

The above will fail with the standard `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method ...` and I get that I can call `db.Products.ToList().Select(...)`, but that is not what I am looking for, as in my case, I am projecting in order to avoid pulling unnecessary data into memory.

I have successfully been using Microsoft.Linq.Translations for custom properties for a while now, however that will not work in my example because I need to pass in a parameter, so a method is really the only way I can see this working.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: See [Linq to entities extension method inner query (EF6)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39623788/linq-to-entities-extension-method-inner-query-ef6), [Projection of single entities in EF with extension methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39623788/linq-to-entities-extension-method-inner-query-ef6) and linked/similar threads.

Comment: I saw that one already, and it didn't provide a solution for a reusable method that returns a collection.

Comment: Well, then you have your answer, right :) Asking a question doesn't mean there is always a solution.

Comment: No, I do not have my answer.

Comment: Read the StriplingWarrior answer (the first link - your question technically is duplicate). `p.GetProductImages(true)` is part of an expression tree, thus cannot be evaluated, hence cannot be converted to SQL. There is fundamental difference between expressions and delegates, although visually they look the same.